# How to insert content script in google chrome extension when page was changed via history.pushState?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-history, vk

I'm creating a small google chrome extension for website, and I want to change some html on particular pages.

The problem is that website load his content via ajax, and heavy use history.pushState API. 
So, I added this thing to manifest:

```
"content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["http://vk.com/friends"],
     "js": ["js/lib/jquery.min.js", "js/friends.js"],      
   },
 ]
```

Everything works fine when I'm opening page first time or reloading it. 
But when I'm navigating between website pages, chrome don't insert my scripts on  "/friends" page. I think this happening because the URL actually don't changing. They use history.pushState() and so, chrome can't insert/rerun my script again.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a [window.onpopstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onpopstate) event in content script and listen for it, when an event fires you can re-run content script again.

**References**

*a)* [extension.sendMessage()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-sendMessage)

*b)* [extension.onMessage().addListener](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#event-onMessage)

*c)* [tabs.executeScript()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript)

*d)* [history.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

*e)* [window.onpopstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onpopstate)

**Sample Demonstration:**

***manifest.json***

Ensure content script injected URL and all API's tabs have enough permission in manifest file

```
{
    "name": "History Push state Demo",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "This demonstrates how push state works for chrome extension",
    "background":{
        "scripts":["background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://www.google.co.in/"],
        "js": ["content_scripts.js"]
     }],
    "permissions": ["tabs","http://www.google.co.in/"]
}
```

***content_scripts.js***

Track for onpopstate event and send a request to background page for rerun of script

```
window.onpopstate = function (event) {
    //Track for event changes here and 
    //send an intimation to background page to inject code again
    chrome.extension.sendMessage("Rerun script");
};

//Change History state to Images Page
history.pushState({
    page: 1
}, "title 1", "imghp?hl=en&tab=wi");
```

***background.js***

Track for request from content script and execute script to the current page

```
//Look for Intimation from Content Script for rerun of Injection
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, callback) {
    // Look for Exact message
    if (message == "Rerun script") {
        //Inject script again to the current active tab
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({
            file: "rerunInjection.js"
        }, function () {
            console.log("Injection is Completed");
        });
    }
});
```

***rerunInjection.js***

Some Trivial code

```
console.log("Injected again");
```

**Output**

[image]

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Btw, pushState doesn't fire "popstate" event, so this code doesn't work.

Answer (score 15):

I was able to get this working. From the [Chrome Extension docs for webNavigation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html#event-onHistoryStateUpdated):

You need to set permissions for `webNavigation` in **manifest.json**:

```
  "permissions": [
     "webNavigation"
  ],
```

Then in **background.js**:

```
  chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function(details) {
        console.log('Page uses History API and we heard a pushSate/replaceState.');
        // do your thing
  });
```