# Content script doesn't re-execute on page reload

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a content script Chrome extension that hides the newsfeed on the Facebook homepage.

This script loads when I first open facebook.com, but fails when navigating into Facebook and back to the main page (which is a URL that's defined in the extension correctly).

Here's my manifest.js file:

```js
{
  "name": "NewsBlock",
  "description": "NewsBlock - Facebook Newsfeed Hider",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "storage"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "NewsBlock",
      "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://www.facebook.com/"],
        "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
    ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Here's my myscript.js file:

```js
if (document.getElementById('home_stream'))
    document.getElementById('home_stream').style.visibility = "hidden";
if (document.getElementById('pagelet_home_stream'))
    document.getElementById('pagelet_home_stream').style.visibility = "hidden";
console.log("NewsBlock Activated...")
```

Any help in understanding why this isn't loaded when I navigate back to the homepage on Facebook will be amazing.

Answer (score 1):

That's because on many occasions the Facebook page uses the [`history.pushstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) method to navigate. This method can change the current url without causing a new page load. The navigation is simulated by replacing part of the page content with the result of ajax calls.

You can use the [`chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html#event-onHistoryStateUpdated) event to detect that situation, as suggested in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17584559/1507998.

Comment: Humm, I just added this :
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function(details) {
      console.log('Page uses History API and we heard a pushSate/replaceState.');
      // do your thing
});

reloaded the extension and I don't get the console.log

Comment: Did you add the `webNavigation` permission? Are you making the call from a background page? `webNavigation` is not available from a content script.

Answer (score 0):

Some links in facebook call ajax functions, so most of time clicking on a link in facebook doesn't change the page, just loads content via ajax. So your content script executes only once.

There are two possible solution,

- You can also add a DOM change listener like DOMSubtreeModified, and run the code every time when content is changed.
- You can add CSS code to page, so it doesn't need to be run every time even if page is changed via ajax.

Like this,

### manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "NewsBlock",
  "description": "NewsBlock - Facebook Newsfeed Hider",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "storage"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "NewsBlock",
      "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://www.facebook.com/"],
        "js": ["myscript.js"],
        "css": ["mystyle.css"]
    }
    ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

### mystyle.css

```
#home_stream, #pagelet_home_stream {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```